# Decimal rounding after upgrade from 4.2.4 to 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some weird problem with decimal attributes after upgrading my application from Rails 4.2.4 to 4.2.5.

I have some classes with decimal attributes, for instance my `Salary` class has a `net_pay`. I have validation on those attributes to verify that they only have two decimals (since it represents money). After the upgrade, all my validation tests for those money attributes failed (tries to set the attribute to a value with more than 2 decimals and verify that the record is invalid). I look at the console and found a strange behaviour:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 18463
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
irb(main):001:0> salary = Salary.new
=> #<Salary id: nil, net_pay: nil, account_debit: nil, payment_at: nil, comment: nil, attachment: nil, approved_at: nil, status: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> salary.net_pay = 123.456789
=> 123.456789
irb(main):003:0> salary.net_pay
=> #<BigDecimal:55b6facd4400,'0.12346E3',18(27)>
irb(main):004:0> salary.net_pay.to_s
=> "123.46"
```

Eh, what? Where did my decimals go?! Notice `0.12346E3`. I tried the same example with 4.2.4 and here is the result:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 18756
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> salary = Salary.new
=> #<Salary id: nil, net_pay: nil, account_debit: nil, payment_at: nil, comment: nil, attachment: nil, approved_at: nil, status: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> salary.net_pay = 123.456789
=> 123.456789
irb(main):003:0> salary.net_pay
=> #<BigDecimal:563cf1cb59d8,'0.123456789E3',18(36)>
irb(main):004:0> salary.net_pay.to_s
=> "123.456789"
```

Why does Rails automatically set the scale of the decimal attributes in 4.2.5 and not in 4.2.4? (Is it a feature? I have declared `scale: 2` in my migration).

## Update

First, I tried to update to 4.2.7.1 directly, then I updated to 4.2.5 and got the same problem.

Diff on my `Gemfile`:

```
-gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
+gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
```

I updated all gems before upgrading Rails, though updating Rails means updating a lot of other gems of course...

And Ruby version is not changed:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! It is actually a feature implemented in `ActiveRecord` 4.2.5 (Rails [Respect scale of the column in the Decimal type](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0b94384bef44535a408b034e44b90d08318e258a)). Sadly, it was not included in the [release notes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-425-november-12-2015) :(